# What does "(unregistered)" mean next to a username

Tags: support

I answered a question from a new user.  I was checking over my recent answers when I noticed that next to the new user it says "TheirUsername (Unregistered)".  Does this mean they deleted their account or deleted their account after asking the question?  (I hope I didn't scare them off with my answer, I didn't use any expletives!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68525/180230) on the main meta site, it's this:

> They haven't registered themselves on the site. They are logged in
>   with a long living cookie tied to a specific PC/webbrowser. They won't
>   be able to login using the same account on other PCs/webbrowsers.